# How to pass some data taken from a child component to another child component?

Tags: angular, input, output

I have to pass some data from child to parent first. After that, the same data is needed to be passed from this parent to another child.

First thing I have done is, I have sent some data from child to parent. But now I need to send this data from this parent to another child, How can I do this.

The three components are,

1. parent1
2. child1
3. child2

child 1 component ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {

  name:string[]
  @Output() messageEvent: EventEmitter<string[]>;
  constructor() {
    this.messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
    // this.name = 'This msg from the child'
  }

  sendMessage(){
    this.messageEvent.emit(['shubham','shubham@gmail.com' ,'9525859898']);
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

-------------------------------------------

parent1  component ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent1',
  templateUrl: './parent1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent1.component.css']
})
export class Parent1Component implements OnInit {
   msg: string;
  constructor() { }
  getMessage($event){
    this.msg = $event;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

child 2 component 2  ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child2.component.css']
})
export class Child2Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() msg
  constructor() { }

  showData($event){
    this.msg = $event
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Since, this needs to be consumed in multiple components with different level of hierarchy, emit via behaviourSubject and subscribe at all places

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of passing data from a child to another child (siblings)

1. Using a **shared service**

You can have a shared service, shared within two child components. Have a behaviour subject in the shared service, and child 2 can subscribe to that. You can update the behaviour subject from child1, and when you do so, child2 will receive the changes.

```
// in your shared service,
sharedData: BehaviourSubject<any> = new BehaviourSubject();

//in your child2 component
sharedService.sharedData.subscribe(value => {
   // do something with your data
}

//in your child1 component
private changeData(data) {
   sharedService.sharedData.next(data);
}
```

2. You can pass data through your parent component

You can use an **event emitter** in your child1 and catch the event from parent. Then you can use **@input()** in your child2  component and pass that data from parent to child2. You can use the **ngOnChanges** life cycle hook to catch changes.

```
// child2
export class Child2 implements onInit, onChanges {
   @Input() msg;

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      if(changes.msg) {
         //do something
      }
   }

}

// parent html
<child2 [msg]="data"></child2>
```

For your question, I recommend the first method, but since you have implemented some codes, the second method would be easier.

Comment: Thank you so much all, am applying these then let you know

Comment: DulanjayaTennekoon I have to pass this data " {{msg}} " how to take it in @input

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to pass data to msg from your parent component. In your child2 component, you can pass that as [msg]="your_field_containing_data"

Comment: DulanjayaTennekoon Actually {{msg}} already containing some data which it took from child 1 and right now it's showing on parent 1, so right now I need to pass that data to child-2, That {{msg}} containing already.

Comment: I have to do like this  child 1 ---@output---> Parent 1 ----@input------>Child2

Comment: [msg]="your_field_containing_data"  but this data - your_field_containing_data is static right ???

Comment: nope. when your child1 emit some new data, you can catch that from your parent. save that data into a separate variable and that variable should be the #your_field_containing_data. It is not static. You can catch the changes using ngOnchanges